# Probleme world generation with thread

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a world generation system.
I have a world class that contain a map of terrain that can be increased during the program.
When I do it in the main thread it work fine but their is little freeze when he calculate the vertex and everything, so I tried to use Thread.

So to generate a terrain I do that :

```
        std::thread newThread(&World::addTerrain, this, xIndex, zIndex, 64, 64);

        newThread.detach();
```

(The addTerrain method)

```
void World::addTerrain(int x, int z, size_t len, size_t col) {
    //allTerrain_[x].emplace(std::make_pair(z, Terrain(x*size_, z*size_, size_ / 2.0f, len, col, &shader_, &heightGenerator_)));
    allTerrain_[x].emplace(std::make_pair(z, Terrain(x*size_, z*size_, size_/2.0f, len, col, &shader_, &waterShader_, &heightGenerator_)));
}
```

but when I do this, the new terrain is added to the map, but he look empty (nothing is drawn).

I'm not sure I'm using the right approach, so if you can help me it will be great !

Comment: If you increase the vector in one thread and read from the same vector in another thread at the same time, you'll probably run into problems. If the vector relocates the data for example, you'll be reading freed memory.

Comment: Yes but I think that's another problem, I could add some mutex, but here when the thread is finished, I still have the problem

Comment: If you've been reading freed memory the state of your program is pretty much undefined.

Comment: How is this related to OpenGL? The issue may come from the way you pass data to GPU, and if you pass if from the worker thread.

Comment: Ohh I need to create the VBO from the main thread ? This must be the issue thanks

Comment: Any OpenGL command must be used in the thread where the "context" is set as current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Add a mutex to `World` (`terrain_mutex_`)
- Use a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` when reading from/writing to `allTerrain_`. Your painting code needs to use this mutex too.
- In `addTerrain`:

```
 void World::addTerrain(int x, int z, size_t len, size_t col) {
    { // lock while copying the terrain
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(terrain_mutex_);
        auto terrain_copy = allTerrain_;
    }

    // add more terrain to the copy
    terrain_copy[x].emplace(z, Terrain(x*size_, z*size_, size_/2.0f, len, col,
                            &shader_, &waterShader_, &heightGenerator_));

    { // lock when swapping in the copy
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(terrain_mutex_);
        std::swap(terrain_copy, allTerrain_);
    }
 }
```